# Citrix Applications : windowed, and using Citrix Receiver Icon

Tags: icons, citrix, xenapp, windowed

Hello my fellow minions :)

Using XenApp 6,5, on a average 100 servers farm.

I'm having trouble with only one Citrix user : All the applications he's using are windowed inside a "receiver window" (for example, outlook is windowed inside a window, using the receiver icon, and named "Outlook - Citrix Receiver").

First problem : all applications are grouped under the same icon in the task bar.
2nd problem : it's crappy as hell to resize all windows (example : the "Outlook Citrix receiver" is 800x600, and the outlook mail inside the window is 1024x768, the user is forced to play with the lifts on the sides of the "Citrix Window" every time he want's to work on it ...

I'm almost sure it's a recurrent problem, but googling it is a pain, since all research with "Citrix receiver window same icon" ends up with a lot of wrong answers/wrong topic answers ...

Any link with documentation will be used and patiently read ...
Thanks you in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one of the Citrix application windows active press Shift + F2 to toggle this view. Sounds like this is what you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you very much ! the user used this keybord shortcut somehow ... and i didn't knew this shortcut ! Problem fixed !

Comment: @Laezylion - Please mark this as the answer for the question. The question still shows as unanswered since no answer was marked correct. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed : The user just used the Shift + F2 shortcut, and don't know how to get out of it ...